# How do multiple gsub() calls work together one after another in awk?

Tags: shell, awk, gsub

Can anyone please help me interpret below awk command?  I am confused with what's the multiple gsub functions doing here.

```
cat vslist.txt | awk '\''/:/{gsub(/ /, \"\", $0);gsub(/{/, \",\", $0);printf $s,$1}'\''");printf "\n"}'
```

**vslist.txt**

```
ltm pool PL_Axxxxx_POOL {
    members {
        ND_APIxxxxxx:7807 {
            address 12.7.21.6
            app-service none
            connection-limit 0
            description none
            dynamic-ratio 1

        ND_APIxxxxxx:7809 {
            address 12.7.21.5
            app-service none
            connection-limit 0
            description none
            dynamic-ratio 1

        ND_APIxxxxxx:7808 {
            address 12.7.21.9
            app-service none
            connection-limit 0
            description none
            dynamic-ratio 1
```

**Output**

```
    ND_APIxxxxxx:7807
    ND_APIxxxxxx:7809
    ND_APIxxxxxx:7808
```

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions are generally outside our scope; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions on [meta]. That said, narrowing the question might improve it: Do you understand what *a single* `gsub` call does? Do you understand one of the `gsub`s but not the other? Or is the real misunderstanding around how they combine?

Comment: BTW, what's with the odd quoting? There are considerably more backslashes here than you'd need to run this in a regular shell context. Is this taken from code that's in some other kind of quoted context?

Comment: ...oh, wait, is `$s` a variable from outside? Okay, passing that variable in the right way (with `awk -v`) would make the rest of your code way easier to read. (Also, we need to know what it contains to be able to properly make sense of this script; code segments should be tested to be complete enough to let someone reproduce the behavior in the question, as described id on the [mcve] page in the Help Center).

Answer (score 3):

`gsub()` calls modify the variable that they're operating on (in this case, `$0`) *in-place*. Thus, one after another, the second one further changes the output of the first.

Consider the following simplified and commented version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  /:/ {                 # run the below code only for lines that contain :
    gsub(/ /, "", $0);  # remove all spaces
    gsub(/{/, "", $0);  # remove opening curly braces
    print $1            # print the first column in what's next
  }
' <vslist.awk           # with stdin from vslist.awk
```

---

#### Debugging With Print Statements (Or, How To See For Yourself)

By the way, one way you could see for yourself how the `gsub()`s interact is by adding extra print statements:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  /:/ {
    print "Input:                                " $0;
    gsub(/ /, "", $0);
    print "After first gsub:                     " $0;
    gsub(/{/, "", $0);
    print "After second gsub, the whole line is: " $0;
    print $1;
  }
' <vslist.awk           # with stdin from vslist.awk
```

---

With that instrumentation, output for your sample input is:

```
Input:                                        ND_APIxxxxxx:7807 {
After first gsub:                     ND_APIxxxxxx:7807{
After second gsub, the whole line is: ND_APIxxxxxx:7807
ND_APIxxxxxx:7807
Input:                                        ND_APIxxxxxx:7809 {
After first gsub:                     ND_APIxxxxxx:7809{
After second gsub, the whole line is: ND_APIxxxxxx:7809
ND_APIxxxxxx:7809
Input:                                        ND_APIxxxxxx:7808 {
After first gsub:                     ND_APIxxxxxx:7808{
After second gsub, the whole line is: ND_APIxxxxxx:7808
ND_APIxxxxxx:7808
```

...so you can clearly see each of the operations take place (the first one stripping off spaces, the second one removing the `{`).